# When several drupal modules implement MODULENAME_template_preprocess, what is the order they are executed?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules, drupal-hooks

I'm asking because it mattered for a [realname issue](http://drupal.org/node/1070102) and it made me think of how to avoid these kind of conflicts.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the same order that module are called : according to their weight. (defined in the database, see 'system' table.)

And if two module share the same weight, then they are called according to their name, alphabetically ordered.

Comment: Minor correction: They are sorted by filename (which is actually the relative path). This means that core modules come before contrib, because *m*odules/... comes before *s*ites/... See http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/function/module_list/6

Comment: Which is nice, if I am writing a contrib module I probably want to work with the output of core modules. The downside is that my profile modules come last!

Answer (score 0):

> Drupal assigns each module a weight.
>   For most operations involving any
>   module that defines a particular hook,
>   the modules are invoked in order first
>   by weight, then by name.

So do note that the `changes made by the last module will` be reflected.

And if you want to change the order of the modules, the answer is [Util](http://drupal.org/project/util), mind you this module does other utilities which come handy as well.